# React Transition Group not applying classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React Transition Group to animate each item with diffrent timeout. The problem is that my links did not receive any classes. However when I wrap ScollLinks tag by TransitionGroup, the animation will work, but the console displays warnings. I have no idea where is the problem.

Props param receive the object with boolean property.

```
const NavItems = (props) => {
 const items = ["section1", "section2", "section3", "section4", "section5"];

 return (
  <>
  <NavItemsOverlay open={props.open} />

  <ScollLinks open={props.open}>
    <TransitionGroup component={null}>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <CSSTransition
            in={props.open}
            key={index}
            timeout={{
              enter: 100 * index,
              exit: 0,
            }}
            classNames="fade"
            unmountOnExit >
            <Link>{item}</Link>
          </CSSTransition>
        );
      })}
    </TransitionGroup>
  </ScollLinks>
 </>
 );
};
```

Comment: What's are those warnings exactly? Can you share them?

Comment: Unknown event handler property `onExited`. It will be ignored. ... and Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `in`.

Comment: Which version of `react-transition-group` are you using in your `package.json` file?

Comment: "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1"

Answer (score 0):

Declare your items outside of the TransitionGroup like this:

```js
const NavItems = (props) => {
  const items = ["section1", "section2", "section3", "section4", "section5"];
  const itemsList = items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <CSSTransition
        in={props.open}
        key={index}
        timeout={{
          enter: 100 * index,
          exit: 0,
        }}
        classNames="fade"
        unmountOnExit
      >
        <Link>{item}</Link>
      </CSSTransition>
    );
  });
  return (
    <>
      <NavItemsOverlay open={props.open} />

      <ScollLinks open={props.open}>
        <TransitionGroup component={null}>{itemsList}</TransitionGroup>
      </ScollLinks>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your example looks good but unfortunately the links still don't have any classes. I removed the TransitionGroup tag and left only CSStransition in map method as above, in a result everything works and the console no longer shows errors. This is strange because I thought that repeated use of CSSTransition requires wrapping by TransitionGroup.